# Should you store an Oauth 2.0 authorization code

Tags: oauth-2.0

Is there any reason to store an OAuth 2.0 authorization code after you've obtained tokens with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the authorization code can be used only once anyway. See https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-10.5:

> Authorization codes MUST be short lived and single-use.  If the
> authorization server observes multiple attempts to exchange an
> authorization code for an access token, the authorization server
> SHOULD attempt to revoke all access tokens already granted based on
> the compromised authorization code.